# Using ISAPI Rewrite 3 & ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, isapi-rewrite, helicontech

I'm using ISAPI Rewrite3 on IIS6 for two Virtual Directories at the moment that contain Wordpress.

I need to setup some rules at the root of the site to redirect old urls to new urls:

```
i.e.

http://www.example.com/somefolder/* > http://www.example.com/newfolder/

&

http://www.example.com/somefolder/file_1.htm > http://www.example.com/newmvcpath/
```

I need to do this without breaking MVC (as its set to wildcard) and without affecting the two virtual directories.

Also how would I set a wildcard up for /somefolder/file_**1**.htm the numeric bit.

Any help greatly appreciated

(heliontech iis rewrite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.htaccess file

```
# Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file
# Version 3.1.0.64

RewriteEngine on

#301 Redirections
#FRANCE (all .html files in a folder)
RewriteRule places-in-france/(.*)\.html places/france [NC,R=301]

#Numeric
RewriteRule companies-france/Companies-in-Pyrenees_(.*)\.htm companies/france [NC,R=301]

#rest of stuff
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Add extensions to this rule to avoid them being processed by ASP.NET
RewriteRule (.*)\.(css|gif|png|jpeg|jpg|js|zip) $1.$2 [I,L]

# Prefixes URLs with "rewritten.aspx/", so that ASP.NET handles them
RewriteRule ^(.*) /rewritten.aspx/$1 [I]
```

Added code to Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
    if (app != null)
        if (app.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath == "~/rewritten.aspx")
            app.Context.RewritePath(
                app.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Replace("/rewritten.aspx", "")
            );
}
```

Using option 4 from this blog http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/  but slightly amended.

This also means I've turned wildcard mapping off.